# Python unittests: setUp using setUpClass

Tags: python, unit-testing

So, I had a lot of unit tests in Python with `setUp` methods.
Some of these `setUp` methods are complicated.

I've found some interesting solution with `setUpClass` class method to execute my `setUp` method just once.

The question is:
how may I use this `setUpClass` classmethod for my tests with prepared `setUp` methods easily?

I was trying to do something like this:

```
class TestSomething(unitest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.setUp()

    def setUp(self):
        # Do some staff.
```

But it didn't work for some reason. `setUp` should be called with a class instance, etc. Not sure if it's the proper way at all.

Comment: Why are you calling the `setUp` method from `setUpClass`? If it's logic you only want to run once, move it to `setUpClass`. If not, let `unittest` call `setUp`.

Comment: So, it's not possible to reuse code from `setUp` in `setUpClass` without refactoring?

Comment: You're already refactoring by adding the class method. It's hard to answer in the general case, as it depends whether your methods actually use any instance state. You may just be able to rename the method and make it a class method.